# Golang middleware authentication depending on route

Tags: go, middleware, negroni

I am building an API in Go. I handle all authentication by including a secret token in the header. I have added some middleware using negroni that picks this out of the header and checks the database to see if it exists.

This is fine but now I want to do permissions based upon the route in question. I have a table in a database with permissions for only some routes etc and I would like to use this logic in the middleware so that the handlers never need to worry about it.

My problem is that the middleware needs to know what handler is being called so that it can check for the correct record in the database. What is the best way to pass or extract the current route / handler using negroni?

Thanks

Comment: ive never used negroni but I suppose you could check `c.Request.Method` and `c.Request.URL.Path` and switch off those

Comment: My only problem with `c.Request.URL.Path` is that it I am using variables in the routes so I would need to do some pattern matching to check it is the route I think it is. Which I can do but it seems inefficient.

Comment: i guess you could manually invoke your permission checks in the handlers like `isRoutePermitted(c, "api.user.create")`? I can't think of anything else built in

Comment: Thanks Plato. I have ended up using your second suggestion. It's not so bad it is just one functional call. Thanks again.